# My scroll view doesn't scroll

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have a xml view like this, and as you see I have scroll view in it, but scroll view doesn't scroll and just match screen size, and I'm not able to see data under the screen.
This is my code: 
CODE HAS BEEN UPDATED

```
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/aboveRelative"
        android:background="@color/darkOrange">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/category_text"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Category"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp" />
        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/topVoices"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:text="@string/topVoices"

                android:paddingLeft="10sp" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/trendlist"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/moreTrend"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:text="More"

                android:paddingLeft="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                android:id="@+id/newVoices"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:text="@string/newVoices"
                android:paddingLeft="10sp" />
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/soundlist"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_below="@+id/newVoices"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/soundlist"
                android:id="@+id/moreNew"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textSize="23sp"

                android:text="@string/more"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/yoursongs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="10dp">

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I'm sure that there are some data under the screen but scroll view doesn't let me scroll it and see them.

Comment: So, it is supposed to have only one child, but looking into your code, I think you do have it. Also, since you are using RelativeLayout, can you see if it somehow ends up in a loop remeasuring your display as it is scrollview? And relativelayout adapts to maximum? I would try to change all RelativeLayouts to LinearLayout, just to see if that is the case. Also, whay don't you remove LinearLayout at the root and leave ScrollView as root?

Comment: I did what you said but the result wasn't different.

Comment: You have a ListView inside a ScrollView, that might not be working? Check this link: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Is explicitly says you should not use a listview inside a scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is wrong. Here's what you gotta do:

1. Change your ScrollView `layout_height` attribute to **`match_parent`**.
   The ScrollView will take the whole screen and make itself scrollable, that's why you need it as match_parent. The scrolling happens inside the View.
2. Put everything inside the ScrollView in a `Linear` or `RelativeLayout`. (see below)
   **The ScrollView extends FrameLayout**, so it can only have a single child view.
   **IMPORTANT:** this layout must have the attribute `layout_height` set to **`wrap_content`**, otherwise the ScrollView won't have anything larger than itself to scroll.
3. I'd also remove the root layout from the XML and leave the ScrollView as root.
   Simply because it's pointless and it requires extra work from the LayoutInflater.

---

**EDIT:** your layout is also way **more complex** that it needs to be.
It lead me to believe you did not have a single child inside the ScrollView (which you *do*).

Still, item #1 should fix your problem.

Comment: I did what you said, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you update you question with the latest XML, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had one item in my original answer but I removed it because your code was already right. Then when you changed what I suggested, you must have accidentally changed it too. Look at your LinearLayout inside of the ScrollView, the topmost one. Its `layout_height` is set to `match_parent`. It can't be, so please change it to `wrap_content` (and only that).

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview layout can only have ONE child layout.  You still have TWO linear layout children in the XML you posted.

This is explained in the first paragraph of the Android developer documentation for ScrollView:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: I put both of them in one linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found answer. The problem was from fillviewport in scroll view. if you remove fillviewport and set fix size for listview, you can scroll.